# What is the best way to type-hint or cast a API function parameter into int?

Tags: php, rest, casting, type-hinting

I'm using Drupal 9 and using OAuth to validate my DELETE API requests. I have a function that responds to DELETE requests and takes student_no as a parameter from the delete request URL. For example, when a delete request https://www.myapplicationurl.com/999999 is sent, my function receives 999999 as student_no. my function is as follows:

```
public function delete( $student_no) {
  $node_array = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(['student_no' => $student_no]);
  $node = reset($node_array);

  if ($node && ($node->bundle() == 'student')) {
    try {
      $node->delete();
      $response_code = 200;
      $response = ["code" => $response_code, "message" => 'deleted', "student_no" => $student_no];

       return new JsonResponse($response, $response_code, $headers);
    } catch (ClientException | RequestException | TransferException | BadResponseException $exception) {
      \Drupal::service('myapi.log_service')->api_log("Stiudent Delete API Exception: {$exception}");
      $response_code = 405;
      $message = json_decode((string) (($exception->getResponse()) ? $exception->getResponse()->getBody() : ''));
      $response = ["code" => $response_code, "message" => 'deleted', "student_no" => $student_no];

      return new JsonResponse($response, $response_code, $headers);
    }
  } else {
    $response_code = 404;
    $response = ["code" => $response_code, "message" => "Student does not exist", "student_no" => $student_no];

    return new JsonResponse($response, $response_code, $headers);
  }
}
```

Now, everything works as expected, but the problem is in my response, $student_no is coming as string like "999999". The var_dump of $response array is : `array(3) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["message"]=> string(7) "deleted" ["student_no"]=> string(6) "999999" }` How can I ensure student_id is always a number? I think I can do two things:

1. I can cast the student number to an integer as the first step inside my function like `$student_no = (int) $student_no;`, but that casts a proper string to 0, for example, if https://www.myapplicationurl.com/somerandomstring is passed, that will effectively set $student_no to 0 after casting. Which I was not sure if the right thing to do.
2. I can type hint student_no as an integer like, `public function delete(int $student_no)` , which seems perfect, but if a string is passed in the url like in #1 above, it gives 500, internal server error, which is a big no-no as it would violate my API contract which only allows me to return 200, 404 or 405 as error codes. For me to implement this, I need to catch the 500 exception, which I'm not sure how to do, otherwise, I have to abandon this approach.

Please suggest the best way forward. Thanks.

Comment: If your function expects only student_no, then why would you care about "somerandomstring" returning 0?. If student_no is 0 then just rejects it since there isn't a student number equals zero is it?

Comment: yes, it seems the possible solution to me as of  to reject 0, but type hinting seemed much better until I realized it can also give 500

Answer (score 1):

You code needs some normalization, and if you explicitly demand `int` then you should do all the validation/sanitization and casting at the place you receive the value (most likely in your controller). From that place that value should fly as `int` or you should stop there if for any reason you cannot properly enforce valid values. Therefore I do recommend you stick to strict type hints in your methods as that's a good way of reducing the potential problems. As for casting issues resulting in `0` values, you first should ensure that this is valid numeric string. There are functions to do that with [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) being the first candidate to look at:

```php
$vals = ['1', 1, '', 'foo', true, -5];

foreach($vals as $val) {
  \var_dump($val);
  \var_dump(\is_numeric($val));
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

producing

```bash
string(1) "1"
bool(true)

int(1)
bool(true)

string(0) ""
bool(false)

string(3) "foo"
bool(false)

bool(true)
bool(false)

int(-5)
bool(true)
```

Alternatively, you may just do pattern matching with `\d+` pattern and only cast if input data matches, not to mention some validation of final integer value (i.e. I do not think you allow negative values for your IDs etc).

Comment: All the values are directly received in this function, so all the checking and validation I can only do here.

Comment: Well, that's no big difference? Only that if you on 8.1 I'd probabky typehint with `string|int` union and then still do `is_numeric()` then `is_string()` and all the stuff as described above. Or just `mixed` and as that'd save at least let me control how to fail if I was fed with wrong data type instead of getting `TypeError`